# How can I use dd to continuously create text files from a file other than /dev/urandom

Tags: dd

I've been using the following command to make dummy files for testing:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=test-file.txt count=100 bs=1024
```

I'd like to use an arbitrary text file instead like "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy". Or maybe some Lorem Ipsum. I tried putting seek=1 in but it doesn't seem to get the job done.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the desired output ?

Comment: Well, there are plenty of lorem ipsum generators out there. You can also use `yes Some String` if you simply want the same string repeated over and over.